# Meteor JS Meteor pages pagination .set() reruns controller

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

For past few hours I tried to solve my problem, the problem is meteor pages package and it's .set() function which causes my controller code to rerun every time it changes (even from javascript console). Let me show you snippets of my code:

autoform hook file:

```
AutoForm.hooks
  handsFilters:
    onSubmit: (data) ->
      # AutoForm.debug()
      # debugger
      @event.preventDefault()

      extendFiltersForHoldem data

      RecentHandsPagination.set
        filters: new RecentHandsFilters(data).setFilters()
      $('#dropdown-recent-hands.open').removeClass('open')
      console.log "onSubmit hook"
      @done()
```

autoform form in html:

```
{{#autoForm schema='HandsFilterSchema' id='handsFilters' resetOnSuccess=false doc=handsFiltersDefaultDoc}}
              <div class="filters-header">
                <h4>{{_ 'filters'}}</h4>
                <a id="clear-form"> {{_ 'clear'}} </a>
              </div>
              <div class="filters-main">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4 filters-game">
                    <label>{{_ 'features.hands.labels.games'}}</label>
                    {{> afQuickField name='pokerGames' id='pokerGames'}}
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 filters-type">
                    <label>{{_ 'features.hands.labels.types'}}</label>
                    {{> afQuickField name='pokerTypes'}}
                  </div>
                  {{> filtersVariants}}
                </div>
              </div>
              {{> filtersChoose}}
              <div class="filters-footer">
                <button data-action='close-hands-filter' type='submit'>{{_ 'buttons.apply'}}</button>
                <small>{{_ 'globalWords.or'}}</small>
                <a href="">{{_ 'buttons.cancel'}}</a>
              </div>
            {{/autoForm}}
```

controller file:

```
class @RecentHandsController extends RouteController
  layoutTemplate: 'recentHands'

  waitOn: ->
    usersIds = _.uniq(Hands.find().map (hand) -> hand.userId)
    Meteor.subscribe 'usersWithImages', usersIds

  data: ->
    Hands.find().fetch()

  onBeforeAction: ->
    console.log "doing onBeforeAction"
    RecentHandsPagination.set
      filters: new RecentHandsFilters().setFilters()
    @next()
```

my pagination instance:

```
@RecentHandsPagination = new Meteor.Pagination Hands,
  availableSettings:
    filters: true
    sort: true
  templateName: 'hands'
  itemTemplate: 'handItem'
  perPage: 30
  infinite: true
  infiniteRateLimit: 1
  infiniteTrigger: 3
  dataMargin: 0
  maxSubscription: 1000
  divWrapper: true
```

Now when I click "Apply" on my form (which is used for setting filters for meteor pages packages) I can see this in my browser's js console:

```
onSubmit hook
recent_hands_controller.coffee:12 doing onBeforeAction
recent_hands_filters.coffee:11 <<<<<<<<<<<@RecentHandsFilters>>>>>>>>>>>>>
recent_hands_controller.coffee:12 doing onBeforeAction
recent_hands_filters.coffee:11 <<<<<<<<<<<@RecentHandsFilters>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your button:

```
<button data-action='close-hands-filter' type='submit'>{{_ 'buttons.apply'}}</button>
```

Change the code to:

```
<button data-action='close-hands-filter' id="applybutton">{{_ 'buttons.apply'}}</button>
```

And give it an event in your template to prevent the event bubbling to submit it:

```
Template.yourTemplateName.events({
    'click #applybutton':function(e,tmpl) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't help, since I'm using autoform I already have called preventDefault() on event. When I applied your suggested code then onSubmit autoform hook didn't run at all.

Comment: @MatthewK Ah I see what you mean. For this you will need to add another button to submit the form. `<button type='submit'>Submit</button>` should do.

Comment: I have some recent conclusions, the problem is not autoform by itself it's the meteor pages package, every single time I change pagination settings, the controller is reran, even if I do it from console level with simple PaginationName.set({filters: {}})